# Need advice for tools to use in everyday workflow

Tags: linux, linux-mint, web, cinnamon

I am an open source web developer that has decided to transition away from using the Microsoft stack as the center of my everyday workflow and dive into Linux for my primary workstation. I would like to knowwhat the most valuable tools are available for common (and not so common) tasks from a web developer's perspective.

Comment: I don't think this question is directly answerable, and will result in opinionated answers.

Comment: Please refrain from using things like `M$` or nOOb…

Comment: This is totally vague. Just tell us what you need. A browser with best JS debugger? A Python IDE, PHP IDE, etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use `FreeMind` mind mapping software, along with `vim` (install plugins and use it like IDE, from temrinal ;) ), learn to use terminal and Linux commands, use `Firebug` for `Firefox`, and `Chrome's Inspector` for Web Front-end debugging, use `Kompozer` to fix the mixed html tag indents and almost all visual web stuff, and many more. I don't know whether I answered your question or not, but I understood it in this way. ;) Have fun with Linux :)

Comment: Why do you recommend these in particular, over the myriad of others? Relative merits of various tools can be both a matter of opinion as well as shift over time, but tool selection criteria stand the test of time much better.

Comment: You're right but I just suggested where to start (as a web developer). I suggested these among dozens of others because they are my favourite ones. After these suggestions, the user will and should learn many others, by himself, ofcourse;)